# Inconsistent behavior in python 2.7.3 with same name of function and local variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

Today I found some weird behavior of following piece of code:

```
if (arg == 0):
   # some local variable
   format = ""
   ret = format + arg
else:
   # bultin format function
   ret = format(arg, "#x")

print ret
```

It acts different inside and outside function.
With this code:

```
import sys

def foo(arg):
   if (arg == 0):
      # some local variable
      format = ""
      ret = format + "0"
   else:
      # bultin format function
      ret = format(arg, "#x")

   print ret


arg = int(sys.argv[1])


print "Outside function:"
if (arg == 0):
   # some local variable
   format = ""
   ret = format + "0"
else:
   # bultin format function
   ret = format(arg, "#x")

print ret


print "Foo call:"
foo(arg)
```

I get following output of call: python format.py 1

```
Outside function:
0x1
Foo call:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format.py", line 31, in <module>
     foo(arg)
  File "format.py", line 10, in foo
    ret = format(arg, "#x")
```

The first question is why a local variable under if statement hides the format function used in else statement?

The second one is why it acts different (and now with the expected behavior) when called outside a function?

Comment: Use [```str.format()```](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of [```format()```](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format).

Comment: It is bad practice to create a variable with the same name as a built-in function anyway; one should never do this. But If you really want to know why it happens, Martin's answer is a very good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python distinguishes between globals and locals; outside the function, `format` is a global, inside the function, `format` is a local *because you assign to it* (if you never bound the name anywhere in the function, it'll be treated as a global instead). You cannot treat a name as both global and local at the same time.

The `if` doesn't matter here; name visibility applies to the *whole scope*; `if` doesn't introduce a new scope, only the function does. So within the function, `format` is a local name, and can never be looked up as a global, regardless of `if` blocks.

Outside the function your code works because there already is a global called `format`; it is a built-in function. If `args == 0` is true, your code will work just *once* as afterwards it'll have rebound the global to a string and future calls to `format()` will fail.

Inside the function, `format` is now a local and never set if `args != 0`; it doesn't matter that the assignment is guarded by `if` here, it is either *always* a local or *always* a global, as this is determined at compile time.

You can easily avoid this problem by not overloading the name `format` here. You don't want to accidentally mask the name `format` *in the first place* as that can break other code that wants to use the `format()` function. For your specific example, it is trivial to just remove the use of `format` altogether:

```
def foo(arg):
    if (arg == 0):
        ret = "0"
    else:
        # bultin format function
        ret = format(arg, "#x")

   print ret
```

You could even just alter the formatting configuration based on the value of `args`:

```
def foo(arg):
    return format(arg, "#x" if args else "d")
```

Comment: @woockashek: but that means the compiler has detected it is a local. You cannot treat it as a global and a local based on dynamic choices here.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.

I'm assigning a value to format only under the scope of if.
I added `print locals()` in else statement and there is only `args` variable so the global `format()` function should not be hidden by a local variable.

Moreover you can delete the call outside the function, so remove any assignment to a global variable and the behavior is still the same.

Comment: @woockashek: that's what I am saying; `format` cannot be looked up as a global, **ever**, because your function **might** use it as a local. In Python, that means it is **always** a local in that function.

Comment: @woockashek the clauses of an `if` statement *don't* have their own scope in Python. See [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: @woockashek: if you delete a global, you get a `NameError` (you can delete built-in names too by removing them from the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)).

Comment: @woockashek: but specifically: `if` doesn't introduce a new scope; only the function has a scope. Within a whole scope, a name is either local or taken from a surrounding scope. It can never be both local and coming from a surrounding scope.

Comment: @Martijn: Ok, now I get the point. I fixed the example by calling explicitly `global format` under else statement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @woockashek Don't use ```global```. It creates a maintainability nightmare. Just name your local variable ```format``` something else.

Comment: @pzp1997: yeah I did this (so change the var name) right after getting this error. I just wanted to know the real cause of the problem.